# Function of RC circuit in a bistable multivibrator using op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

What is the purpose of the RC circuit in a bistable multivibrator?

Can't we obtain the same result, if the trigger input is supplied directly (bypassing the RC circuit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of R-C circuit in bistable multivibrator, based upon an op-amp, is to create the pulse input to the op-amp to make it switch between the positive and negative saturation voltages of the operational amplifier operating with the given supply voltages.

> [image: Simple bistable multivibrator circuit]

The capacitor let's through (i.e. charges upon) the edge of the input signal and then decays through R<sub>1</sub> thereby providing the pulse required.

A positive pulse switches the op-amp to its negative saturation, whereas a negative pulse swithes the op-amp to its positive saturation.

> [image: Waveforms for the bistable multivibrator circuit]

---

Source: [Op Amp Bistable Multivibrator Circuit Design](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/bistable-multivibrator-circuit-design.php)

Comment: Can't we obtain the same result..If the trigger input is given directly...?

Comment: Hmmm, good question, and one that changes the nature of your original question (I've added it to your original post). If the trigger input is already a pulse then yes. If it isn't (i.e. a square wave), then I must admit that I'm not sure. BTW, is the schematic that I showed the schematic that you were asking about - it wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: Yeah..schematic is what i had in my mind...but rc circuit(given) is a high pass filter right?...so,how does it allows a dc spike??

Comment: Yes, it is a high pass. It's not a dc spike, as such. The filter allows the rising edge through, but removes the dc level thereafter, hence the pulse.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote. Thx. I wouldn't accept this answer yet though, as someone else can probably answer why a pulse is strictly necessary.